# How can I restore my default python install on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, pyobjc

I'm trying to install pyobjc (using pyobjc-1.2-python2.3-macosx10.2.dmg) on a Mac running OSX 10.6 and I get the following error message:

[image]

To use Python 2.3 I tried re-editing my .bash_profile and I commented out everything with the exception of this line:

```
# change python version 
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.3
```

I did previously include this:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin${PATH}"
export PATH
```

but at the moment left it out. I know that when I type `python` in the terminal it gives me `Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29)` so it clearly is not using 2.3.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of `PyObjC` is *very* old.  It may not even run on Mac OS X 10.6.  Further, Apple doesn't ship a full python2.3 with OS X 10.6.  The Apple-supplied Python 2.6 (`/usr/bin/python2.6`) already has `PyObjC` installed.  If you need an even newer version, installer the latest [Python 2.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) (or [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/)) using a OS X installer from the `python.org` website, install `easy_install` for that Python using [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/) or [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/), and then install [PyObjC from PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc/2.3):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/easy_install pyobjc
```

You should undo the effects of that `defaults` command, too.  It is only going to cause problems.

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
```

Comment: I downloaded that version of PyObjC from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyobjc/ Is there a more recent one?

Comment: But I think I was just on the wrong site. Thanks for the advice - I successfully installed it using easy_install. However I did have to specify which gcc compiler to use "export CC=gcc-4.0" as the default compiler throws the following error "cc1: error: unrecognized command line option “-Wno-long-double” is what threw me off originally.